# How to achieve custom jQuery page scroll api as in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I recently came across one of Google's projects "What do you love" and saw a nice feature there.

If you visit http://www.wdyl.com/#monkeys
On your left you will see a small box that allows you to scroll the page "Quiet Cool" I thought when I saw it ))) I looked over the internet to find jQuery plugins or Tutorials on how to do similar thing (jQuery/javascript is not my strong side), but I couldn't find any.

So could anyone please explain how to make similar "Api/Feature" and provide code snippets if possible, that would really help. Ohh an jQuery solution is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is so frequently the case, your best bet is to open your browser's Developer Tools and look at what's actually going on there!  In this case, it looks like a static background (the grey boxes) with a blue frame on top of it, somehow made draggable, that calls one of the window scrolling functions after doing a bit of proportions arithmetic to determine how far to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demo I put together to show you how to animate the scroll of a page: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/3cnKn/1/

In my example, the basic idea is to bind to a `click` event for some links and animate the `scrollTop` of the `html` element:

```
$('#nav').find('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html').animate({scrollTop : $(this).attr('data-scrollTop')}, 500);
});
```